# Use ByteBuffer in MediaExtractor

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am looking to create a MediaExtractor interface with a ByteBuffer instead of a file. Does know if this is currently possible by some roundabout means?

I see [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/DataSource.java) that there is a setDataSource(DataSource) method, but I am not sure how to access that since it is declared `@hide`.

If I could both create and access these methods and classes using reflection, I would happily take that solution and run with it as long as possible.

However, I wonder if someone has figured out a better way to implement the MediaExtractor with a byte array instead of a fully-formed file (since I might want to play audio from a ring buffer).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused - could you please elaborate? MediaExtractor's readSampleData() returns a ByteBuffer from a file, but you are asking to replace the ByteBuffer with a file? Also, I have problem accessing the link, can you provide short summary/description of the relevant parts?

Comment: No, I am asking if there is a simple way to pass MediaExtractor.setDataSource with a byte buffer.